# Saving Y position of UIViewSubclass Does not Have member Named Error

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, position

Im trying save the position of a `UIView` subclass that is moved via a `pan gesture recogniser` and needs to stay in that position

The UIView Subclass `MoveSection`

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("reposition:"))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

        let yPosition = self.frame.origin.y

    }



 func reposition(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {


        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)
        if let view = recognizer.view { view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x, y:view.center.y + translation.y)

        }

        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self)

        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            //Center view
           self.center.x = self.bounds.width/2

         }

    }
```

Save position in class

```
class ViewController

@IBOutlet var reorderSectionOne: MoveSection!

let positionDefaults = NSUserDefaults()
positionDefaults.setObject(NSStringFromCGPoint(self.reorderSectionOne.yPosition), forKey: "pointPositionSectionOne")
positionDefaults.synchronize()
```

Error: Does not have member named  yPosition

Comment: What is the type of `reorderSectionOne`? Can you please show where you declared `reorderSectionOne`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the declaration of `yPosition` from inside `init(coder:)` to just inside your `UIView` subclass. Also, `yPosition` is a `CGFloat`, not a `CGPoint`. So I used a different instance variable, called `savedCenter`, to save the position as an actual `CGPoint`. I've refactored your code and implemented the changes below.

```
class MoveableView: UIView {

    var savedYPosition: CGFloat!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"reposition:")
        self.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)

        self.savedYPosition = CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)
    }

    func reposition(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)

        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x + translation.x, view.center.y + translation.y)
        }

        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self)

        if recognizer.state == .Ended {
            // center view
            self.center.x = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / 2.0
        }

    }

}
```

And then you would put the following in your `ViewController` class

```
func savePosition() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults()
    defaults.setFloat(Float(self.reorderSectionOne.savedYPosition), forKey: "yPositionSectionOne")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Note that I assumed your `UIView` subclass was named `MoveableView`.

Comment: Doesn't that just save the centre position though? Thats just a snapping tool, im trying to save the y position not the centre position

Comment: @JSA986 Edited. How's it look?

Comment: looking good but still having no member named error in my `viewControllerClass` hmmm

Comment: @JSA986 How about now?

Comment: Thats got it!, your a gent! Thanks for that